# Get all months included between two dates in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

This questions will seems similar to old ones about month but I have a special issue.
I am not trying to count the months between two dates, but I am trying to get the months included in two dates.
I explain. I have 2 dates :

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2014-07-20' );
$end = new DateTime( '2014-10-10' );
```

Between those two dates, I have 4 months included : July, August, September, October.
But with the script I am using, I am not able to find 4 months included but only 3. This is the script :

```
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');

$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
$counter = 1;

foreach($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format( 'm' );
    $counter++;
}

echo $counter;
```

How to count all those 4 months in a loop ?

Comment: I wish to make a loop throught all those months

Comment: Your example will work only for cases where day in $begin will be smaller than day in $end. Easy solution would be to set day in $begin to 1st day in month, and set day in $end to any day not 1st (2nd, 3rd, or last). [Example of your modified code.](https://eval.in/191289)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with simple `while()` loop:

```
$begin = new DateTime('2014-07-20');
$end = new DateTime('2014-10-10');

while ($begin <= $end) {
    echo $begin->format('Y-m'), "\n";
    $begin->modify('first day of next month');
}
```

**<kbd>[demo](https://eval.in/191283)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks Glavic, this is very elegant... And it works very well!

Comment: If $begin>$end, it shows nothing. So if you want the list regardless a day of a month, you need some corrections: `$begin = (new DateTime('2014-07-20'))->modify('first day of this month'); $end = new DateTime('2014-07-01');` It will show "2014-07" for such a case;

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$begin = new DateTime( '2014-07-20', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris') );
$end = new DateTime( '2014-10-10', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris') );
$end->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');

$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
$counter = 0;

foreach($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format( 'm' );
    echo "\n";
    $counter++;
}

echo $counter;
```

It seems to be a bit tricky, but it should work with any date (i haven't tested a lot tho). I just added a month to the `$end` date so that it takes account of the fact you want to get all the included months in a certain date interval.

Comment: Ok, but if you make a loop with the foreach, you will notice the problem is still the same @Lgt

Comment: The problem with the interval here is that it seems to be counting 30 days equivalent to months, it is not telling me which months are in the interval.

Comment: Is it better now ? I haven't tested it a lot, but it works.

Comment: It seems not to be working for 2014-07-01 to 2014-09-30 ... Can you test ? It says 4 months but it is only 3

Comment: It seems the only way to really loop between months is to loop through days of the interval and get months.

Comment: @pollux1er: this example won't even work for dates which begin on day that next month doesn't have. Example: 2014-08-31 + 1month is 2014-10-01 (month 09 is skipped from the loop). My example/answer will work in any-case-scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
$begin = strtotime('2014-07-00');
$end= strtotime('2014-10-00');
$y1 = date('Y', $begin);
$y2 = date('Y', $end);
$m1 = date('m', $begin);
$m2 = date('m', $end);
$diff = (($y2 - $y1) * 12) + ($m2 - $m1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this is not an optimal solution but it is working well :

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2014-07-20' );
$end = new DateTime( '2014-10-10' );
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$months = array();
foreach($period as $dt) {
    if(!in_array($dt->format( "m" ), $months)) {
        $months[] = $dt->format( "m" );
        echo  $dt->format( "m" );
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```